# Error when trying to set up conquer of completion in neovim, "complie coc.nvim by: npm ci"

Tags: neovim

[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxlZZ.png)

I have been trying to set up COC in neovim and have installed node.js and npm, but every time i open up neo vim I get the error message "complie coc.nvim by: npm ci". can anyone help?

i tried re-installing and i receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use the `release` branch of coc.nvim.

If you want to use `master` branch, `cd` to your plugin directory, in `coc.nvim` folder to rum `npm ci` to build.

If you're using plugin manager, you can setup like:

Recommend: `Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}`

`Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'master', 'do': 'npm ci'}`